# Method name expected displaying strings in label c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to add a specific part of a string to a label in c#
I only want the string up to the space to be displayed (in line 6 of this code)

```
bool BoolSpace = s.Contains(" ");
if (BoolSpace == true)
{
    int IntSpacePos = s.IndexOf(" ");
    int StrPos = IntSpacePos - 1;
    LblLmcCode1.Text = LblLmcCode1.Text + s(0, StrPos);
}
else
{
    LblLmcCode2.Text = LblLmcCode2.Text + '\n' + s;
}
```

However line 6 is returning an error method name expected about the 's' of s(0, StrPos)

Comment: `s` appears to be a `string`, so what are you trying to do by `s(0, StrPos)`? Are you looking for `s.Substring(0, StrPos)`?

Comment: Line 6 is not "returning an error method name". Are you saying there's a compiler error because there's no method called `s`? Of course there isn't. What are you trying to do there?

Answer (score 5):

You should use `Substring` method:

```
s.Substring(0, StrPos);
```

All together with fewer lines:

```
LblLmcCode1.Text = LblLmcCode1.Text + s.Substring(0,  s.IndexOf(" ") - 1);
```

Also as `BoolSpace` is a boolean itself no need to check if it is equal to true but it is enough to write `if(BoolSpace)`, and better still just place the `Contains` in the statement:

```
if(s.Contains(" "))
{
    LblLmcCode1.Text = LblLmcCode1.Text + s.Substring(0,  s.IndexOf(" ") - 1);
}
else
{
    LblLmcCode2.Text = LblLmcCode2.Text + '\n' + s;
}
```

Comment: @BethanLaw - Glad to help :) Please consider marking question as solved once the 15 mins pass if this solved your problem